# Проверить PHP функцию

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Написал функцию, принимает 2 параметра:
`$phone` - может быть как строкой, так и массивом строк
`$patter` - шаблон, под который будут изменяться строки

Суть работы функции, приводить формат строк (номера телефона), в формат указанный в шаблоне (`$pattern`)

```
# Pattern format "# (###) ###-##-##"
function PhoneFormat($phone, $pattern = "# (###) ###-##-##") {
    if(is_array($phone)) {
        foreach ($phone as &$item) {
            $item = PhoneFormat($item, $pattern);
        }
        return $phone;
    } 
    else {
        $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
        if(substr_count($pattern, "#") != strlen($phone)) 
            return false;
        for($i = 0, $k = 0; $i < strlen($pattern); $i++) {
            if($pattern[$i] == "#")
                $pattern[$i] = $phone[$k++];
        }
    }
    return $pattern;
}
```

Как вам алгоритм с точки зрения эффективности и реализации?
Правильно было ли применять рекурсию?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Для замены символов формата на цифры можно использовать встроенную ф-ю [`vsprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.vsprintf.php) – которая «впечатывает» в формат переданные значения. Например:

```
vsprintf('%d-%d(%d)', array(1,2,3)); // "1-2(3)"
```

План такой: разбить только-цифры телефона в массив, по одной, и «впечатывать» их [в формат](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php), в котором вместо `#` стоит место-под-число `%d`:

```
    $phone = str_split( preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone)); // массив цифр
    if(substr_count($pattern, "#") != count($phone))  return false;

    // знак процента – специальный, его, если есть 
    // в исходном паттерне, надо заменить на %%
    // и # меняем на %d
    $format = str_replace( array('%','#'), array('%%','%d'), $pattern);
    return vsprintf( $format, $phone);
```

Оптимизировать можно момент обработки самого формата. Он задаётся всего один раз при внешнем вызове ф-ии `PhoneFormat()`, поэтому в случае с массивом телефонов, не нужно каждый раз снова считать кол-во символов `#` в нём, его длину (`strlen($pattern)`) в вашем варианте, и его перевод в формат для `vsptinf()` в предложенном моём варианте – всё это достаточно сделать всего один раз и запомнить - в глобальных переменных, либо обернуть всё в класс, либо передавать 3-м и 4-м параметрами при вызове функции.

Answer (score 0):

Код неплохой.
Можно завершить начатое дело (обработка $phone на месте), что упростит программу.

Где-то так:

```
# Pattern format "# (###) ###-##-##"
function PhoneReformat(&$phone, $pattern = "# (###) ###-##-##") {
    if(is_array($phone)) {
        foreach ($phone as &$item) {
            PhoneReformat($item, $pattern);
        }
    } 
    else {
        $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
        if(substr_count($pattern, "#") != strlen($phone)){
            $phone = false;
        }else{ 
            for($i = 0, $k = 0; $i < strlen($pattern); $i++) {
                if($pattern[$i] == "#")
                    $pattern[$i] = $phone[$k++];
            }
            $phone = $pattern;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока не могу оставлять коментарии, так что ответом. Очень понравился кусок substr_count($pattern, "#"), в качестве забавной зарядки сделал вариант без $k. Очевидно, что и читаемость кода и, вероятно, скорость исполнения страдают, но цель была не в этом.

```
function PhoneReformat(&$phone, $pattern = "# (###) ###-##-##") {
if(is_array($phone)) {
    foreach ($phone as &$item) {
        PhoneReformat($item, $pattern);
    }
}
else {
    $phone = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $phone);
    if(substr_count($pattern, "#") != strlen($phone)){
        $phone = false;
    }else{
        foreach(str_split($pattern) as $key => $char){
            if ($char == "#") {
                $pattern[$key] = substr($phone, -substr_count($pattern, "#"), 1);
            }
        }
        $phone = $pattern;
    }
  }
}
```